# Struts2 Tag retrieve a Single fieldError as text only

Tags: forms, jsp, struts2

How do I retrieve a single fielderror without any formatting?

I want just the plain text message without any formatting  in a jsp is that possible?

This can be done in an action but how would I do this inside a jsp?

```
System.out.println(this.getFieldErrors().get("fileMissing"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using JSTL you can do this

```
<c:out value="${fieldErrors['passwordError']}"/>
```

and for struts tag, you can do this

```
<s:property value="fieldErrors['fileMissing']"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use  [**`<s:fielderror />`**](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/fielderror.html) in your jsp like this:

```
<s:fielderror fieldName="fileMissing"/>
```

Comment: this does not work. I simply adds a field error at the top of all field in the s:form

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:property value="fieldErrors['fileMissing']"/>
```

Comment: please explain your answer

Comment: It's really the same a KyleJmD's answer... I think if you check ActionSupport you'll see a map of some type used to hold fieldErrors. Using the s:property or c:out you can access this map. s:fielderror tag is a shortcut, since it knows where to look (see Ankur's answer) or better struts2 tag reference docs.